# Working Xbox Kinect support within python?

Tags: python, kinect, pykinect

Does anyone know of any up to date or close to that package for using an xbox kinect within python or a way to use an older version of any packages out there?

After trying to use pykinect the install fails due to an out of date windows sdk which I couldn't seem to download through there website due to a newer version being available and not being able to go back to previous versions.

Any suggestion?